# iFrame not loading in angular 5

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to load an iFrame in my angular 5 app using the following code, but for some reason it is not launching the iFrame unless I do print() on the load()

```
  let iframe = document.getElementById('print_iframe');

  iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.setAttribute('id', 'print_iframe');
  iframe.setAttribute('name', 'print_iframe');
  iframe.setAttribute('width', '0');
  iframe.setAttribute('height', '0');
  iframe.setAttribute('frameBorder', 'no');
  iframe.setAttribute('src', 'about:blank');
  iframe.setAttribute('sandbox', 'allow-same-origin allow-modals');
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);

  iframe['contentWindow'].document.open();
  iframe['contentWindow'].document.write(output);
  iframe['contentWindow'].document.close();
```

Unless, I add this code it is not launching the iFrame, which is strange. I don't see any console errors either. Please help

```
  iframe['contentWindow'].onload = iframe.onload = function () {
  iframe['contentWindow'].print();      
}
```

Comment: What unexpected behaviour make you believe the iframe is "not loading"? I don't understand because I can tell from description that iframe DOM element obviously *has been loaded* onto the main frame DOM, and the content of iframe also has been loaded because `onload` is called. Please be more specific about the expected behaviour. What exactly do you mean by the word "loading".

Comment: @hackape - thanks for trying to help me. I'm expecting to see that pop up window loaded through that iFrame, but unless I use the print() on the onload() function the window is not getting launched, but I don't want to print anything and just show the popup window with the passed in content.

Comment: What "that popup window"? Still don't get it, I don't see any popup window mentioned in your question. If you cannot state your problem clearly with written words, then provide a minimum reproducible code example would be easier to make your point.

Comment: I'm launching the iframe as a popup window and writing my result on to that window.